# If else statement in select query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have query written below If my counter is coming then there should show Yes, if no value is coming then No will be there.Please have a look on query.
the output should be as below

```
   KU      Electrical  
Yes   6       2  
No    1       2
```

6 is counter of KU and Yes refers the presence,similarly No is non presence of KU

```
select SalesChannel.name , 
Transaction.category_id, 
count(Transaction.category_id) as count,   
from outlets Outlet inner join transactions Transaction on Outlet.id = Transaction.outlet_id inner join sale_channels SalesChannel on SalesChannel.id = Outlet.sale_channel_id group by SalesChannel.name
```

below are three tables which i used

1. transactions

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `model_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `outlet_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_of_units` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mop` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `transactions`
--

INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`, `zone_id`, `state_id`, `city_id`, `category_id`, `sub_category_id`, `brand_id`, `model_id`, `outlet_id`, `no_of_units`, `mop`) VALUES
(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, '6.00'),
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, '6.00'),
(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, '2.00'),
(4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, '2.00');
```

2.outlets

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `outlets` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `outlet_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_channel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `outlets`
--

INSERT INTO `outlets` (`id`, `outlet_code`, `name`, `zone_id`, `state_id`, `city_id`, `sale_channel_id`, `is_active`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, '1508', 'Ashok electricals', 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, '2016-10-03 00:00:00', '2016-10-03 00:00:00'),
(2, '1233', 'vinayak electricals', 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, '2016-10-04 00:00:00', '2016-10-04 00:00:00');
```

3. sale_chennals

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sale_channels` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sale_channels`
--

INSERT INTO `sale_channels` (`id`, `name`, `is_active`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 'KU', 1, '2016-10-03 00:00:00', '2016-10-03 00:00:00'),
(2, 'Electricals', 1, '2016-10-04 00:00:00', '2016-10-04 00:00:00');
```

Comment: There is no way for us to know what KU is, or where it comes from. it's not in your query and we have no idea what your data set looks like.

Comment: @TimothyGroote i am adding my table structures

Comment: you can learn about that here : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/3307/select#t=201610071007067637909

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'case' in the query

select SalesChannel.name , 
Transaction.category_id, 
count(Transaction.category_id) as count, **case when count(Transaction.category_id)>0 then 'Yes' else 'No' as KU**
from outlets Outlet inner join transactions Transaction on Outlet.id = Transaction.outlet_id inner join sale_channels SalesChannel on SalesChannel.id = Outlet.sale_channel_id group by SalesChannel.name

Answer (score 0):

I have added an a additional row to the outlets table so that the following query fails to find a transaction.
(3, '3333', 'abc electricals', 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, '2016-10-04 00:00:00', '2016-10-04 00:00:00');

```
select  t.srce
            ,sum(case when s.name = 'KU' then 1 else 0 end) KU
            ,sum(case when s.name = 'Electricals' then 1 else 0 end) Electricals
from
(
select 'yes' srce, o.id,  o.sale_channel_id, t.category_id  
from outlets o 
join transactions T on O.id = T.outlet_id 
union all
select 'no' srce, o.id, o.sale_channel_id, t.category_id  
from outlets o 
left outer join transactions T on O.id = T.outlet_id
 where t.outlet_id is null
 ) t

 JOIN  sale_channels s on  t.sale_channel_id = s.id

 group by t.srce
 order by case
                when t.srce = 'yes' then 1 
                 else 2
             end;
```

The inner sub query gets outlets with transactions using a join and outlets without transactions using an outer join/null method. The outer query then uses conditional aggregation to produce the output

Result

```
+------+------+-------------+
| srce | KU   | Electricals |
+------+------+-------------+
| yes  |    3 |           1 |
| no   |    0 |           1 |
+------+------+-------------+
```

If you have an unknown number of sales_channels you may need to use dynamic sql.

```
set @sumstr = 
(select str from
(
select @rn:=@rn + 1 rn,@str:=concat(@str,'sum(case when s.name=',char(39),s.name,char(39),' then 1 else 0 end) as ', s.name, ',' ) str
from (select @rn:=0,@str:='') str,sale_channels s
) s
order by rn desc limit 1
);


select concat(
'Select t.srce, ',substr(@sumstr,1,length(@sumstr) -1) ,
' from
(
select ', 
concat(char(39),char(121),char(101),char(115),char(39)) , 
' srce, o.id,  o.sale_channel_id, t.category_id  
from outlets o 
join transactions T on O.id = T.outlet_id 
union all
select ' , 
concat(char(39),char(110),char(111),char(39))  ,
' srce, o.id, o.sale_channel_id, t.category_id  
from outlets o 
left outer join transactions T on O.id = T.outlet_id
 where t.outlet_id is null
 ) t
 JOIN  sale_channels s on  t.sale_channel_id = s.id
 group by t.srce
 order by case
                when t.srce = ' ,
                     concat(char(39),char(121),char(101),char(115),char(39)) ,' then 1 
                 else 2
             end;   
'
)
;
```

Comment: what about dynamic names . you have added static. I want dynamic database fields. how it can be?

Comment: before we go down that road how many sales channels do you have?

Comment: its dynamic filed. there are so many. it comes from table . the name of the table is sale_channels and name is field whrre KU, Electricals names are saved

Comment: P.Salmon. can you change it in all dynamic values please. you have almost done but only this thing needs to be done. thn i would love to rate you. please help P.Salmon.. :)

Comment: please give me answer. how I can make it dynamic